# update an object with useState hook in React

Tags: reactjs

I have an object in board variable

Initial Data:

```
const [board, setBoard] = useState({
    lanes: [],
});

{
    lanes: [{
            title: 'Bugs',
            id: 'd83706b0-b252-11ec-8845-ad6b1e4ecd03',
            cards: [{
                id: null,
                title: 'Bug #1',
                description: 'Can AI make memes',
            }, ],
        },
        {
            title: 'Tests',
            id: 'd83706b0-b252-11ec-8845-ad6b1e4ecd04',
            cards: [{
                id: null,
                title: 'Test #1',
                description: 'Can AI make memes',
            }, ],
        },
    ],
};
```

I want to add a new element to the **cards** array but only to the first element in the **lanes** array. Other answers seem to point to having to use a callback pattern, but I am quite unfamiliar with this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When should the element be added? What did you try?

Comment: this `setBoard({...board, lanes: [{ ...board.lanes[0], cards: [...board.lanes[0].cards, newCard] }, ...boards.lanes.slice(1)],});` is a bit verbose but should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for any modification you want to do on a useState variable, you must use an arrow function inside of the "set" function.

You can do something like that :

```
setBoard((currentBoard)=> {
    currentBoard.lanes[0].cards = [...currentBoard.lanes[0].cards, whateverCardYouWantToAdd ]
    return {... currentBoard} //necessary to create a new object because else the hook won't be updated
})
```

Comment: thanks so much! this does work, but it seems to trigger twice. Must have something to do with the re-render. I am triggering this onClick

Comment: Hmm, I see, I guess it has more to do with when you call setBoard than with its content, but I can't say more without knowing more of your code. Good luck :) Happy to help !

Answer (score -1):

Maybe with this.

```
const addValue = () => {
    let t = [...board];
    t[0].lanes.cards.push({
        id: null,
        title: "Bug #1",
        description: "Can AI make memes"
    });
};
```